# (Tensorflow, Keras) UnicodeDecode Error shown while defining datasets for Training and Validation. How do I resolve this?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

**Code:**

```
    image_size = (180,180)
    batch_size =1

    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        'add',
        validation_split=0.9,
        subset= 'training',
        seed = 20,
        image_size = image_size,
        batch_size = batch_size,
    )
    val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
       'add',
        validation_split=0.9,
        subset = 'validation',
        seed = 20,
        image_size = image_size,
        batch_size = batch_size,
    )
```

**Expected output:**
Found 34 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 4 files for training.
Found 34 files belonging to 2 classes.
Using 30 files for validation.

**Error shown:**

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\user name\Desktop\ABC\Programming projects\Project\Project (1).ipynb Cell 3 line 4
      1 image_size = (180,180)
      2 batch_size =1
----> 4 train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
      5     'add',
      6     validation_split=0.9,
      7     subset= 'training',
      8     seed = 20,
      9     image_size = image_size,
     10     batch_size = batch_size,
     11 )
     12 val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
     13     'add',
     14     validation_split=0.9,
   (...)
     18     batch_size = batch_size,
     19 )

File c:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\image_dataset.py:210, in image_dataset_from_directory(directory, labels, label_mode, class_names, color_mode, batch_size, image_size, shuffle, seed, validation_split, subset, interpolation, follow_links, crop_to_aspect_ratio, **kwargs)
    208 if seed is None:
    209 seed = np.random.randint(1e6)
--> 210 image_paths, labels, class_names = dataset_utils.index_directory(
    211     directory,
...
--> 703   return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
    704 except errors.OpError:
    705   return False

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 67: invalid continuation byte
```

And the path of both the datasets is actually `c:\Users\user name\Desktop\ABC\Programming projects\Project` and not `c:\Users\user name\Desktop\ABC\Programming projects\Project\Project`
as shown in the error.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)